# Assign new string to an HTML element using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to reuse a var to load a new string.

So here are my attempts.

```js
function hello() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one').value;
  var two = document.getElementById('two').value;
  var msg = document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '';

  if (one !== two) {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Fields do not match";
    return false;
  } else {
    msg.innerHTML = "Fields match";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return hello()">
  <input type="text" name="one" id="one">
  <input type="text" name="two" id="two">
  <input type="submit" value="Test this thing">
</form>
<p id="message"></p>
```

I've already declared the message var outside the function, so I don't want to repeat the full row inside the function...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Get rid of `= ''` at the end of the line that assigns to `msg`.

Comment: You're setting `msg` to the empty string, not the element.

Comment: Donde that, and I get noting when fields match :-(

Comment: `var msg = document.getElementById('message'); msg.innerHTML = 'Fields match'; if (one !== two) { msg.innerHTML = 'Fields do not match'; return false; } return true;`. That's all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');
var msg = document.getElementById('message');

function hello() {
  msg.innerHTML = one.value === two.value ? "Fields match" : "Fields do not match";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return hello()">
  <input type="text" name="one" id="one">
  <input type="text" name="two" id="two">
  <input type="submit" value="Test this thing">
</form>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Comment: I Love shorthand comparisons, Thank You, Nenad.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `msg`, it should just be the result of calling `getElementById()`, not the `innerHTML`. And you shouldn't assign `''` to it at the same time.

You were setting `msg` to an empty string, so you can't then use `msg.innerHTML`.

```js
function hello() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one').value;
  var two = document.getElementById('two').value;
  var msg = document.getElementById('message');

  if (one !== two) {
    msg.innerHTML = "Fields do not match";
    return false;
  } else {
    msg.innerHTML = "Fields match";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return hello()">
  <input type="text" name="one" id="one">
  <input type="text" name="two" id="two">
  <input type="submit" value="Test this thing">
</form>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Comment: Thank You Barmar.... Excellent explanation. Thank You * 3